# How do i get the following boxed align along with a tag on the side?

Tags: formatting

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, amsthm}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{upgreek}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
```

Id like to get the following result but i can't seem to workout a boxed align with the text on the side
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help you:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\fbox{%
  $\begin{aligned}
    E &= h\nu = \hbar\omega\\
    \mathbf{p} &= \hbar\mathbf{k}
  \end{aligned}$%
}\tag{Planck-Einstein relations}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: perfect this is exactly what i wanted. Also super easy solution thanks.